# SQL SSIS syntax question

Tags: ssis, syntax

What do you call the following expression?

`(TableName == NULL) ? "0"  : TableName`

I have a sense of what it does, but would like to look up the whole syntax definition, however as there is no real descriptor in the expression I can't seem to find out what it's called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's what is known in programming as a [Ternary Operator](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/operators/ternary-operator.html). It's common in C/C++, JavaScript and PHP (among other languages).

As tombom states, the idea is that it is a short-hand `if` statement:

```
<condition> ? <true-case-code> : <false-case-code>;
```

SQL Server 2012 and above has it's own Ternary Operator in the form of the `IIF` statement.

```
IIF(@type = 2, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Marking this one as correct because it has a linked reference, and is the first answer that contains the actual name.

Answer (score 1):

This is short for

```
<if> ? <then> : <else>
```

at least in programming that is, like in C++ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This type of expression is called a Ternary operator. Its standard form is

```
condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false
```

Using your example of

```
(TableName == NULL) ? "0": TableName
```

if TableName == NULL then "0" is returned

if TableName !==Null then TableName is returned

You could rewrite the ternary expression as

```
if(TableName==NULL) then "0" else TableName
```

but this is more verbose than the original Ternary expression.